# Prove this inequality $1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots+\frac{x^n}{n!}>\frac{e^x}{2}$

Tags: inequality, exponential-function

let $0<x\le n$,prove that
$$1+x+\dfrac{x^2}{2!}+\dfrac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots+\dfrac{x^n}{n!}>\dfrac{e^x}{2}$$

Now I have prove $x=n$ case and my methods is very ugly,but $x\in(0,n]$,I can't prove it 
Thank you

the following it's $x=n$ solution
show that
$$1+\dfrac{n}{1!}+\dfrac{n!}{2!}+\cdots+\dfrac{n^n}{n!}>\dfrac{e^n}{2},n\ge 0,n\in Z$$

use this 
$$e^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac{n^k}{k!}+\dfrac{1}{n!}\int_{0}^{n}(n-t)^ne^tdt$$

then
$$\Longleftrightarrow n!>2e^{-n}\int_{0}^{n}(n-t)^ne^tdt$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow \int_{0}^{\infty}t^ne^{-t}dt>2e^{-n}\int_{0}^{n}(n-t)^ne^tdt$$
let $u=n-t$ 
$$\Longleftrightarrow \int_{0}^{\infty}t^ne^{-t}dt>2\int_{0}^{n}u^ne^{-u}du$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow \int_{n}^{\infty}u^ne^{-u}du>\int_{0}^{n}u^ne^{-u}du$$
let $f(u)=u^ne^{-u}$
$$\Longleftrightarrow  f(n+h)\ge f(n-h),0\le h\le n$$
This is very easy.

Comment: are you allowed to use the power series representation of $e^x$?

Comment: you mean this $e^x=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^n}{n!}$ ?

Comment: Do you need to prove equality holds for $x=n$ or the inequality?

Comment: Thank you,@Inceptio, I hope prove this inequality in $x\in(0,n]$,when $x=n$ I have prove it.

Comment: I think you can do this by letting $x := \lambda n$ where $0 \lt \lambda \le 1$. All your inequalities will remain true.

Comment: Thank you,@ApprenticeQueue Then we don't prove it

Comment: @math110, I meant replace your argument of $x=n$ with $x=\lambda n$ and you will arrive at the same conclusion you have for $x=n$.

Comment: No,you mean we must prove this  $$1+\lambda n+\dfrac{\lambda^2}{2}n^2+\cdots+\dfrac{\lambda^n}{n!}n^n>\dfrac{e^{\lambda n}}{2}$$,But this is not easy.

Comment: @math110, it is the same.  You only need to show $n! > 2e^{-\lambda n} \int^{\lambda n}_0 (\lambda n -t)^n e^t dt$ which follows basically what you have already.

Comment: oh, This is good hint.Thank you @ApprenticeQueue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a reduction to the case $x=n$.

Notice that by integration by parts we have
$$\int_x^\infty \frac{t^n}{n!} e^{-t} \, dt = e^{-x}\left(1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \dots + \frac{x^n}{n!}\right).$$

Thus it is enough to show that
$$\int_x^\infty \frac{t^n}{n!} e^{-t} \, dt > \frac{1}{2}.$$
But clearly $\int_x^\infty \frac{t^n}{n!} e^{-t} \, dt \ge \int_n^\infty \frac{t^n}{n!} e^{-t} \, dt$ when $0 < x \le n$.

Comment: It's very nice,Thank you ! +1

Comment: Once again, thank you, I solved the problem on a recent

Comment: Why does (if it does) last inequality implie that the integral is $>1/2$?

Comment: @Kazz8,because I have prove it $$\int_{n}^{\infty}\dfrac{t^n}{n!}e^{-t}dt=e^{-t}\left(1+n+\dfrac{n^2}{2!}+\cdots+\dfrac{n^n}{n!}\right)>\dfrac{1}{2}$$